# Why do people vote down answers that I have posted but are an answer in the comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, voting, unanswered-questions

I once saw a really good answer in the comments, but the question was unanswered and I (please don't say I'm a plagiariser)  took that answer in the comments and made it into an answer and reworded it differently.

I didn't want the question to remain unanswered, but the answer I put (which was the only one) got -3 votes and I ended up deleting it.

This happened again, but that time I credited the person, and I got -5 votes on it, so I deleted it again.

Finally, this happened on another SE Q&A site, but I didn't cite the author this time, and the answer is at 0 votes.

---

Can anyone explain why people don't like this?

Comment: Maybe there were reasons why others answered in comments and not writing an actual answer.

Comment: Seems to me people don't like that kind of behavior. Maybe you should be supplying your own answers instead of poaching?

Comment: Also how did the Questions' score look when you posted your answers?

Comment: I think answers belong to the answer section, and expanding a comment into an answer is a service when attributed properly. If a question shouldn't be answered, it shouldn't be answered in the comments either.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta So report the comment (or even better communicate with a moderator of the community) to decide what should be done.  In other words, get the comment deleted, then submit an answer (but the comment should be reported either way) but I suspect the downvotes has nothing to do with you turning a comment into an answer.  Can you provide screenshots of those answers?

Comment: @Ramhound here is the link to the -3 question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177396/anatomizing-lua-code-with-lua-itself/51200246#51200246 I cannot put the answer back for 5 days b/c my account is suspended. Sadly, the I cannot find the second one with -5

Comment: So you failed to mention the fact there are two different meta questions, as a result of the comment you used to answer the question.  You should seek advice from the SO community, on how to improve your answer, since I cannot see the deleted answer (which is the reason I asked for a screenshot of the answer), I can only assume the votes were justified.

Comment: @Ramhound when my account gets unsuspended, I will undelete it. also i have credited the the author in that one

Comment: @TrooperZ - You should leave it deleted.  The votes against the answer were justified.